# How to write an update query that can mix capital letters and small letters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to running and update query in SQL Server but I'm not getting the right result.

I have this code

```
UPDATE tableEE 
SET ascode = LOWER('aaBBCCddEE67=') 
where ascode='zzzXXXyyy=' --
```

I get an output as `'aabbccddee67='`
Also, I tried this code:

```
UPDATE tableEE 
SET ascode = UPPER('aaBBCCddEE67=') 
where ascode='zzzXXXyyy=' --
```

And I get an output as:

```
'AABBCCDDEE67='
```

Also tried:

```
UPDATE tableEE 
SET ascode = ('aaBBCCddEE67=') 
where ascode='zzzXXXyyy=' --
```

This code will give me all in caps

```
UPDATE tableEE 
SET ascode = ('aaBBCCddEE67=') 
where ascode='zzzXXXyyy=' --
```

I want my result to be the actual characters that I input, eg

```
'aaBBCCddEE67='
```

but my actual result is

```
'AABBCCDDEE67='
```

Comment: It will give you the same  value 'aaBBCCddEE67=', which you assigning in set

Comment: That because you are using `UPPER()` and `LOWER()` functions, so get ride of them and just assign `SET ascode = 'aaBBCCddEE67='`

Comment: the results look right except the last one as SET ascode = ('aaBBCCddEE67=') should show the results as entered. In any case... please, provide DDL for your question.

Comment: Please could you [edit] the question to show the definition of the table `tableEE`, and the `SELECT` query you're using to view the data afterwards.

Comment: If you want to be remain as actual values then you don't need to put anything extra in set statement.

Comment: Unable to understand last four lines of question which is confusing and I think that contains actual requirement.

Comment: My comment from your (almost exactly the same) deleted question still stands: *"You state that `UPDATE tableEE 
SET ascode = ('aaBBCCddEE67=') where ascode='zzzXXXyyy='`still stored all the value as uppcase letters. If that DID store `'AABBCCDDEE67='` that **strongly** implies there is a trigger on your table too."* I suggest giving us the DDL for that trigger this time please.

Comment: Actually i dont the DDL that triggers this.

Comment: If you can't access the DDL of the trigger, I suggest talking to your database developer; obviously the trigger is there for a reason and you're trying to get a round it (which is likely not a good idea).

Answer (score 4):

Simply, this will give the right results, unless you have a trigger or something else you don't tell us about it

```
UPDATE tableEE 
SET ascode = 'aaBBCCddEE67='
where ascode='zzzXXXyyy=';
```

Comment: that's code that he showed us, and he says it is all in CAPS

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine, after talking to the developer , he said its something that have to do with the DDL triggers..

UPDATE tableEE 
SET ascode = 'aaBBCCddEE67='
where ascode='zzzXXXyyy=';

Thanks to everyone for the great contributions